# Gather both first and lastname into a full name

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I started working with my first app for angular it is such that I must have showcased full name when one has written both names into first and last name.

What I mean is that the few first name and last name and indicate the full name overall. Right now the problem is such that it does not add the full name total at all.

**UsersCreate.js** - (*I'm sure that the fault lies around here*)

```
var UserCreatenNow = angular.module('UserCreatenNow', []);

UserCreatenNow.controller('CreateUserNow', function ($scope) {
    //checking on first name and surname are written.
    if ($scope.name != null && $scope.lastname != null)
    {
        //prints it together
        $fullname = "Welcome to " + $scope.name + " " + $scope.lastname;
    }
});
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
<div ng-app="UserCreatenNow" ng-controller="CreateUserNow">
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Fornavn)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Fornavn, new
               {
                   @class = "form-control",
                   @ng_model = "name",
                   @placeholder = HelperTextClass.HelperText.placeholderInfo.Fornavn
               })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Fornavn, "", new
               {
                   @class = "label label-danger"
               })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Efternavn)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Efternavn, new
               {
                   @class = "form-control",
                   @ng_model = "lastname",
                   @placeholder = HelperTextClass.HelperText.placeholderInfo.Efternavn
               })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Efternavn, "", new
               {
                   @class = "label label-danger"
               })
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
         <p class="label label-danger"></p>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create user {{fullname}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't add `fullname` to the scope. `$scope.fullname`

Comment: `$scope.name` will always be null in your `if`. That condition will only be evaluated at run time of controller

Comment: @charlietfl It will not really present it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$fullname` is not on the scope. Try this:

```
//prints it together
$scope.fullname = "Welcome to " + $scope.name + " " + $scope.lastname;
```

Comment: Try to bind the inputs to an object instead of directly to the scope.
So the scope is something like this:
$scope.user = {name: '', lastname:''}

Comment: Thanks for help. Now its work for me. i giv u +1 and i hope u will giv me a +1 for its.